# How can I show and hide elements based on selected option with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, html-select

Here is my code. Why it doesn't work?

```
<Script> 
   $('#colorselector').change(function() {
        $('.colors').hide();
        $('#' + $(this).val()).show();
 });
</Script>
<Select id="colorselector">
   <option value="red">Red</option>
   <option value="yellow">Yellow</option>
   <option value="blue">Blue</option>
</Select>
<div id="red" class="colors" style="display:none"> .... </div>
<div id="yellow" class="colors" style="display:none"> ... </div>
<div id="blue" class="colors" style="display:none"> ... </div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as getElementById not find the element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element)

Answer (score 89, accepted):

You're running the code before the DOM is loaded.

Try this:

**Live example:**

http://jsfiddle.net/FvMYz/

```
$(function() {    // Makes sure the code contained doesn't run until
                  //     all the DOM elements have loaded

    $('#colorselector').change(function(){
        $('.colors').hide();
        $('#' + $(this).val()).show();
    });

});
```

Comment: Works and +1 for linking to jsfiddle.net

Comment: I have a small question. What should I do if I have to show same div section based on two or more select option values? I don't want to add additional div section. Like - Show red based on red and yellow values.

Comment: @yogsma - You could simply give those `<option>` elements the same value, since you're using the `value` attribute to grab the proper `div`.

Comment: what if it gets the value of the option "Red mango" and finds the div that has a title "Red mango", can this be possible???

<Select id="colorselector">
   <option value="Red mango">Red mango</option>
</Select>
<div class="colors" style="display:none" title="Red mango"> red... </div>

Comment: beautifully simple. Works great

Comment: What do I change `.val()` to in order to get the class of the option instead of the value? Is it as simple as `.class()` or `.getclass()` ?

Comment: thanks it is nice solution. @user113716 anyway how to do if my value is already selected then show div also.

Answer (score 19):

```
<script>  
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#colorselector').on('change', function() {
      if ( this.value == 'red')
      {
        $("#divid").show();
      }
      else
      {
        $("#divid").hide();
      }
    });
});
</script>
```

Do like this for every value

Comment: Your solution is the best of all, as it gives full freedom to do anything easily. I removed the else statements and utilized only the if statements for flexibility. Published it on jsfiddle at [http://jsfiddle.net/FvMYz/6587/](http://jsfiddle.net/FvMYz/6587/)

Answer (score 4):

To show the div while selecting one value and hide while selecting another value from dropdown box: -

```
 $('#yourselectorid').bind('change', function(event) {

           var i= $('#yourselectorid').val();

            if(i=="sometext") // equal to a selection option
             {
                 $('#divid').show();
             }
           elseif(i=="othertext")
             {
               $('#divid').hide(); // hide the first one
               $('#divid2').show(); // show the other one

              }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You are missing a `:selected` on the selector for `show()` - see the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/) for an example of how to use this.

In your case it will probably look something like this:

```
$('#'+$('#colorselector option:selected').val()).show();
```

Comment: No need to get the specific `option:selected`. Calling `.val()` on the select itself will return the value of the selected option. :o)