# moving visible divs' onto the hidden divs' position

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a dropdown in a div. when I select different options from dropdown menu, I need to show  different divs' based on the value selected. I am hiding the other divs when I am showing a div. but I am getting empty space in hidden divs' position. how can I move the visible div to immediatley below the dropdown always ?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: Use `display: none`, not `visibility: hidden`, then you shouldn't get empty space.

Comment: Refer this,I think It may help you..
<http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2975521/show-hide-div-based-on-select-option-jquery>?

Comment: read up on CSS: `z-index`, `float`, `display`, `overflow`... all useful rules

Answer (score 0):

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/f9npF/)

JQUERY :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#drop').change(function () {
        if ($('#drop option:selected').text() == "Volvo"){
            $('div').hide();
            $('#volvo').show();
        } else if ($('#drop option:selected').text() == "Mercedes"){
            $('div').hide();
            $('#mercedes').show();
        } else if ($('#drop option:selected').text() == "Audi"){
            $('div').hide();
            $('#audi').show();
        } else {
            $('div').hide();
        } });
});
```

HTML:

```
<select id="drop">
  <option value="">--select--</option>
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
<div id="volvo">u have selected volvo</div>
<div id="mercedes">u have selected mercedes</div>
<div id="audi">u have selected audi</div>
```

CSS:

```
div{display:none;
width:40%;
background-color:#EBFFC2;
border-radius:5px;}
```